# Determine compile options from load module - IBM Enterprise COBOL

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos

How can I determine the compile options used to compile an IBM Enterprise COBOL program by looking at the load module? When a dump is issued they are listed as follows:

```
Compile Options for PROGXX:                                                 
  ADV, ARITH(COMPAT), AWO, NOCICS, CODEPAGE(01140), DATA(31), NODATEPROC,   
  NODBCS, NODLL, NODYNAM, NOEXPORTALL, NOFASTSRT, INTDATE(LILIAN),          
  NUMPROC(NOPFD), NOOPTIMIZE, OUTDD(SYSOUT), PGMNAME(COMPAT), RENT, RMODE(AN  
  NOSQL, SQLCCSID, SSRANGE, NOTEST, NOTHREAD, TRUNC(OPT), XMLPARSE(XMLSS),   
  YEARWINDOW(1900), ZWB
```

so I presume they must be tucked away somewhere in the load module.

I want to scan a load library checking that each load was compiled with some specific options to ensure compliance to shop standard (eg. SSRANGE).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Update**

I have since written an LE Cobol load module scanning program which does this job and a bit more besides. If you are interested check out: http://www3.sympatico.ca/bredam/LoadInfo.html

Comment: Usually SYSADATA is used for that. Unless you are not generating it. Format for SYSADATA is here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ratdevz/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.ent.cbl.zos.doc/topics/PGandLR/ref/rpadt02.htm. I guess the same format is replicated in the load module, so you may search for it. I'm not posting as an answer because not sure ...

Comment: @belisarius. Good suggestion. SYSADATA would be fine if the datasets were saved, but I'm looking at a bunch of load modules that have a suspicious "pedigree" - hence wanting to verify the compile options directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is a start. [`From the CBT Tape:`](http://www.cbttape.org/)

```
//*                                                                 *   FILE 551
//***FILE 552 is from Marc Manuel, and contains a COBOL 2 and       *   FILE 552
//*           COBOL/MVS analysis program.  This program will list   *   FILE 552
//*           the compile options of COBOL load modules.            *   FILE 552
//*                                                                 *   FILE 552
//*           email:  "MANUMAN" <manuman@club-internet.fr>          *   FILE 552
```

Something in there may be useful ...

Comment: Thanks, CBT Tape was the place to go. I think file 347 MODLIST fits the bill perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Roland Schiradin's COBANAL is free, or there's the commercial product [Edge Portfolio Analyzer](http://www.edge-information.com/epa-00.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There is quick mainframes tutorials and compiler options at link
http://techpalli.blogspot.com/p/mainframes.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it describes various compiler options, what they do, and how to set them. What I am trying to do is determine which compile options were specified at compile time given the resulting load module. Basically I have to reverse engineer part of the load module (tricky but dooable).